How to make one curve in graph editor for multiple channels?
I'm making an animation. My objects move and rotate on different axes, so if I e.g. want a the object to first move quickly and then slowly, I have to manipulate every single one of the six transform channels, and it takes a hell lot of time to make all of the objects slow down in a same speed, so there wouldn't be a moment where e.g. it would move slowly on the X and quickly on the Z axis.
I know that, for such simple things as speeding up, I can just select all keyframes and make them sinusoidal and with an ease-out easing. But most of the time those automatic options are just not enough.
Is there any way to manipulate many bezier-curves in many channels at once? Or, even better, connect e.g. all location transform channels to one curve? I doubt that it exists in normal blender, but I'm sure that someone had to run into the same problem and create some addon. I tried searching it online, but found nothing.

Maybe the Tween function of the GraphKit Addon.
https://blendermarket.com/products/graphkit


Thanks! GraphKit didn't solve my problem, but another addon from the same creators did. Here's link if anyone else might need it: https://blastframe.com/product/animcopy/
